# PHP - isolate first letter from a text

Tags: php, html, string

I have a set of articles, in which I want to style the first letter from each article (with CSS).

the articles usually start with a paragrah, like:

```
<p> bla bla </p>
```

So how could I wrap the first letter from this text within a <`span>` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = '<p> bla bla </p>';
$search = '_^<p> *([\w])(.+) *</p>$_i';
$replacement = '<p><span>$1</span>$2</p>';

$new = preg_replace( $search, $replacement, $str );

echo $new."\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you need to do something *extremely* fancy, there's also the [:first-letter CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in all CSS.

CSS supports "Pseudo-Elements" where you can choose the first letter / first word and format it differently from the rest of the document.

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/CSS_pseudo_elements.asp

There's a compatibility chart; some of these may not work in IE 6

http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Comment: They almost all work in IE7 and they all work in IE8. IE6 has problems, but it has problems with lots of things.

Answer (score 1):

you could add a Php span but might not be as clean
$s = "

la la

";
$strip = trim(strip_tags($s));
$t = explode(' ', $strip);
$first = $t[0];

// then replace first character with span around it
$replace = preg_replace('/^?/', '$1', $first);

// then replace the first time of that word in the string
$s = preg_replace('/'.$first.'/', $replace, $s, 1);

echo $s;

//not tested

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a versatile method yet, but a traditional code implementation (that may be slower) works:

```
function pos_first_letter($haystack) {
  $ret = false;
  if (!empty($haystack)) {
    $l = strlen($haystack);
    $t = false;
    for ($i=0; $i < $l; $i++) {
      if (!$t && ($haystack[$i] == '<') ) $t = true;
      elseif ($t && ($haystack[$i] == '>')) $t = false;
      elseif (!$t && !ctype_space($haystack[$i])) {
        $ret = $i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Then call:

```
$i = pos_first_letter( $your_string );
if ($i !== false) {
  $output = substr($s, 0, $i);
  $output .= '<span>' . substr($s, $i, 1) . '</span>';
  $output .= substr($s, $i+1);
}
```